# How to make devexpress gridcontrol's indicator display text bold

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol

How can I make the display text in devexpress gridcontrol's indicator **bold**?

Changing the indicator cell style here also changes the background color. But I just want to make the indicator cell display text bold, with default background color.

```
    e.Appearance.FillRectangle(e.Cache, e.Bounds);
    e.Appearance.DrawString(e.Cache, e.Info.DisplayText, e.Bounds, 
          new Font(e.Appearance.Font.FontFamily,10,FontStyle.Bold), 
          new StringFormat());
    e.Handled = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use this code:

```
_gridView.RowCellStyle += GridViewRowCellStyle;

void GridViewRowCellStyle(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
    FontStyle fs = e.Appearance.Font.Style;
    fs |= FontStyle.Bold;
    e.Appearance.Font = new Font(e.Appearance.Font, fs);
}
```

if you have editors, add this:

```
_gridView.ShownEditor += GridViewShownEditor;

void GridViewShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FontStyle fs = _gridView.ActiveEditor.Font.Style;
    fs |= FontStyle.Bold;
    _gridView.ActiveEditor.Font = new Font(_gridView.ActiveEditor.Font, fs);
}
```

And for indicator the same:

```
_gridView.CustomDrawRowIndicator += GridViewCustomDrawRowIndicator;
void GridViewCustomDrawRowIndicator(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FontStyle fs = e.Appearance.Font.Style;
    fs |= FontStyle.Bold;
    e.Appearance.Font = new Font(e.Appearance.Font, fs);
}
```

Comment: `private void gridViewArticles_CustomDrawRowIndicator(object sender, RowIndicatorCustomDrawEventArgs e) { //row indicator cell style needed. not simply gridview cell }`

Comment: @ВадимДворак the same as GridViewRowCellStyle, I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can set style of focused row in your grid. Grid => GridView => Appearance => FocusedRow => Font => Bold set to true.